# Spring Security - alwaysRemember property in AbstractRememberMeServices

Tags: spring, spring-security

I 'm using the "Remember me" function in "Spring Security 4".
I need to set to true the 'alwaysRemenber' property in the 
'AbstractRememberMeServices' . How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this depending on your rememberServices.

```
 <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
 </security:http>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="myAppKey" />
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="customUserDetailsService" />
        <property name="alwaysRemember" value="true" />
    </bean>
```